# Xamarin Forms Localization using Resx

Tags: xaml, localization, resx

I've followed this quick lesson to add localization to a XamarinForms app:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?pivots=windows#specify-the-default-culture

Their provided project works correctly - in that I can change languages by changing [assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US")] in AssemblyInfo.CS.

In my own project, using the same ResX strings in a XAML layout I cannot change the language from anything other than en-GB.

Comment: It would be helpful if you include the relevant parts of your code, rather than desiring them.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts The issue, in my mind, is that I'm unsure of which bits are relevant. As far as I can tell my code imitates exactly the project supplied in their link. I mean there must be something missing or it would work! I will add code snippets to the original.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts And removing the AppResource files and readding them seems to have fixed something. All working.

Answer (score 0):

Edit - Removing resx files and recrafting seems to have done the trick.